# Backbone, rest, populate collection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, rest, backbone.js

I'm trying to do my first webapp with backbone/mvc3 and i would like to have some advices to populate a collection.

Here is a part of my collection

```
window.TaskList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Task,

    url: "../../api/Tasks";
},.......
```

I can use the crud methods to get/update the models but i've the following problem :

When i open the page, my collection is populated (calling the get method serverside) But i would like to have this kind of behavior :

- Page 1 : put/delete/get methods => as usual but the collection has to be populated calling the getTasksByWorkshopId serverside method
- Page 2 : put/delete/get methods => as usual but the collection has to be populated calling another serverside method to filter the list
  ...

(ie : i cant filter the collection client side because of the amount of data)

So, my question is : how to keep a generic collection url (as api/Tasks) and populate the collection with another method (do i have to override smth ?)

(sorry for this newbie question)

Thanks in advance

Comment: The `url` property can be a function. There's also the `urlRoot `property of Backbone collections. If you pass something into the collection's `options` object that specifies which URL to use, you could write the url function to return the appropriate URL based on those options.

Comment: Thanks for your help but (sorry), i donno how to use it. I mean i defined an urlRoot (api/tasks) and the url is a function (if page 1 => url = this.urlRoot + '/Workshop/' + workshopId; else .... ). BUT i've the same pb, when the collection i populate with the good method (/tasks/workshop/1) but the getter called is the url called is /api/Tasks/Workshop/1/141 instead of /api/Tasks/141.

Comment: I've added an answer that should solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a comment to the other answer you said that "When the collection is loaded, the url called is /api/Tasks/Workshop/1 (the good one) but, when i want to update a task, the url called is /api/Tasks/Workshop/1/141 instead of /api/Tasks/141."

In order to "update a task" (a task model, I assume) to a different URL, then your Collection & Model should have different URLs. If you define a collection without specifying the `model` property, the URL used when saving/fetching/deleting a model will be based off of the collection's URL. The same is also true if the collection's model has no defined url property. See below.

Also, [**JSFiddle example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/CoryDanielson/sn9zJ/).

```
var WorkshopModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "api/tasks/"
});

var WorkshopCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: WorkshopModel,
    urlRoot: "api/tasks/workshop",
    url: function() { return this.urlRoot + '/' + this.id; },

    initialize: function(models, options) {
        this.id = options.id;
    }
});

var c = new WorkshopCollection(null, { id: 1 });
c.fetch();         // GET    =>    api/tasks/workshop/1

var m = c.add({ id: 300, color: 'red' });
m.save();          // PUT    =>    api/tasks/300
m.destroy();       // DELETE =>    api/tasks/300
m.fetch();         // GET    =>    api/tasks/300
```

If you remove the `urlRoot` property from the WorkshopModel, then the URL that the models use will be the `collection.url() + '/' + model.id` ( api/tasks/workshop/1/300 )

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :

```
window.TaskList = Backbone.Collection.extend({

    model: Task,

    urlRoot: "../../api/Tasks",

    url: function() {

        if (/*page 1*/) { // you can access this.options where you can pass parameters to distinct the 2 services, when calling the fetch function
            return this.urlRoot + // getTasksByWorkshopId URL ;
        } else {
            return this.urlRoot + // the other service URL ;
        }
    } ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. i already tried something like this. When the collection is loaded, the url called is /api/Tasks/Workshop/1 (the good one) but, when i want to update a task, the url called is /api/Tasks/Workshop/1/141 instead of /api/Tasks/141. And i'm not sure the best way is to do some custom routes to use /Tasks/workshop/1/141 as /Tasks/141. Thanks

Comment: what's your urlRoot ?

Comment: My urlRoot is something like you did : 
window.TaskList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Task,
    urlRoot: "../../api/Tasks",
    url: function() {
        if (/*page 1*/) { 
            return this.urlRoot + '/Workshop/' + workshopId;
        } else {
            return this.urlRoot ;
        }
    }
}

Comment: You need to change the URL on the model, then.